# Estilos dots Slick Carousel

Tags: css, slick-carousel

Saludos me podrían ayudar con este tema, he intentado monton de opciones pero no logro llegar al estilo que necesito, adjunto la imagen de lo que necesito, y mi codigo es:

```
.slick-dots {
  top: 182px;
  right: -102px;
  display: grid;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%; /* color of container */
}
.slick-active button::before{
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
}
.slick-dots li button::before {
  color: #000; /* color of dots */
  opacity: .25; /* opacity of dots */
  background-color: transparent;

}
```

asi es como deberia quedar, a ubicaiocn ya lo tengo solo necesito darle ese efecto de sombra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias de antemano.